# CSS Media Query Image still loads if query overwrites it later?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Suppose we have a css stylesheet that dictates the following on a `div`

```
.my_div{
    background-image: url(../some/image.png);
}
```

Then, for mobile, we have another style sheet that overrides that:

```
@media (max-width: 400px){

    .my_div{
        background-image: none;
        background-color: rgb(12, 13, 14);
    }
}
```

Will `../some/image.png` still get loaded if the device satisfies the `@media (max-width)` query?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested this, but yes, theoretically it will load and then be overwritten if the media query is satisfied.  If you're trying to make a "mobile first" design, consider changing the order. Remember that CSS is cascading, very particular about the *order:*

```
.my_div {
    /* load this first for "mobile" */
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgb(12, 13, 14);
}

/* and then this for desktop, notice "min-width" instead of max-width */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
   .my_div{
       background-image: url('../some/image.png');
     }
}
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) is a pretty good read about the logic.